# White marks around leaders in PDF

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, output, output-driver, leaders

Why are there white bars between the leaders and each of the rules in this code when compiled with LuaTeX to a PDF file? When compiled (with LuaTeX) to a DVI file no white bars can be seen.

```
a \vrule width10pt\leaders\vrule\hfill\vrule width10pt\ b
```

Comment: This might be a "smoothing" issue. Try to turn off optimization options like "smooth text" in the viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not get white bars:

```
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\pdfcompresslevel=0

a \vrule width10pt\leaders\vrule\hfill\vrule width10pt\ b

\bye
```

> [image: Result]

Also the PDF page stream code looks correct:

```pdf
q
1 0 0 1 100.227 759.927 cm
0 0 9.963 6.918 re f
Q
q
1 0 0 1 110.19 759.927 cm
0 0 410.992 6.918 re f
Q
q
1 0 0 1 521.182 759.927 cm
0 0 9.963 6.918 re f
Q
```

Horizontal positions

- First rule: left = 100.227, width = 9.963 → right = 110.19
- Leader rule: left = 110.19, width = 410.992 → right = 521.182
- Last rule:   left = 521.182, width = 9.963 → right = 531.148

Therefore it is very likely an issue with the PDF viewer, which you are using.

However, the three rules can be merged to one rule:

```tex
a \leaders\vrule\hskip 20pt plus 1fill\relax\ b
```

PDF code shows one rule:

```pdf
q
1 0 0 1 100.227 759.927 cm
0 0 430.917 6.918 re f
Q
```

Comment: I think you do---zoom in the image you posted and you should be able to see them more clearly. I admit that the bars are not exactly white but somewhat greyish. Otherwise, "my" PDF contains the same page stream code like the one you posted. Also, I tried two viewers: Evince 2.30.3 and Okular 0.10.5; both showed the bars in question.

Comment: @AngelTsankov: The image was created by ghostscript 9.05. Here indeed a green line can be seen. But I couldn't see a lighter line neither in AR9/Linux, xpdf 3.04, okular 0.14.3. It is an artefact of the PDF viewer: If I change `-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4` to `-dGraphicsAlphaBits=1`, the grey line is gone.